# PowerShell 2 equivalent to Enable-NetAdapterBinding

Tags: powershell, networking

The following script works for PowerShell 4 but I need to figure out its equivalent for systems with PowerShell 2.  The purpose of the script is to enable the `File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks` across all network adapters on a system.

```
$adapters = Get-NetAdapter

Foreach($adapter_name in $adapters) {
Enable-NetAdapterBinding -name $adapter_name.name -ComponentID ms_server
}
```

I found PowerShell 2 code for the first part to get the adapter names but not the second part that enables the feature.

```
$adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetConnectionID
```

Comment: The cdxml cmdlet modifies `ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapterBindingSettingData`